# Correct way of unit-testing classes that use DateTimeOffset objects?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datetime, testing, nunit

I would appreciate information or examples about how to correctly test code that uses DateTimeOffset instances. I know the tests have to be deterministic.

So, how would one isolate the application from the DateTimeOffset classes ? I would, of course, like to be able to use a fake DateTimeOffset.Now, etc.

In my tests, should I be using something like:

```
var myDate = new DateTimeOffset(2016, 3, 29, 12, 20, 35, 93, TimeSpan.FromHours(-3));
```

Or would I instead be using a wrapper class like MyCustomDateTimeOffset ?
Should I not use DateTimeOffset at all in my code and use a wrapper instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the [fundamentals theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering) says:

> We can solve any problem by introducing an extra level of indirection.

You don't really need a wrapper, all you need is to avoid `DateTimeOffset.Now`/`DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`.

Here are a few ways you could handle that:

- If you use dependency injection, write an `IClock` interface which exposes the `Now`/`UtcNow` properties.

  ```
  public interface IClock
  {
      DateTimeOffset Now { get; }
      DateTimeOffset UtcNow { get; }
  }

  internal class Clock : IClock
  {
      public DateTimeOffset Now => DateTimeOffset.Now;
      public DateTimeOffset UtcNow => DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
  }
  ```

  In your tests, you just mock the interface as you wish.
- If you'd rather keep using a static property, write a static type, let's say `Clock`, and use that.

  ```
  public static class Clock
  {
      internal static Func<DateTimeOffset> DateTimeOffsetProvider { get; set; }
          = () => DateTimeOffset.Now;

      public static DateTimeOffset Now => DateTimeOffsetProvider();
      public static DateTimeOffset UtcNow => DateTimeOffsetProvider().ToUniversalTime();
  }
  ```

  In your tests, you can substitute `DateTimeOffsetProvider`.

  Here's a .NET 2 version:

  ```
  public static class Clock
  {
      internal delegate DateTimeOffset DateTimeOffsetProviderDelegate();
      internal static DateTimeOffsetProviderDelegate DateTimeOffsetProvider { get; set; }

      public static DateTimeOffset Now { get { return DateTimeOffsetProvider(); } }
      public static DateTimeOffset UtcNow { get { return DateTimeOffsetProvider().ToUniversalTime(); } }

      static Clock()
      {
          DateTimeOffsetProvider = delegate() { return DateTimeOffset.Now; };
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but would the second version (which I like much more) work with a .NET 2.0 project? Do you know if there's other way of doing that for .Net 2.0? Thanks

Comment: For use in .NET 2, you'd only need to replace `Func<T>` with a custom delegate, I added some code to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you won't know the value of DateTimeOffSet.Now, then all you can't assert that DateTimeOffSet.Now equals a value.

You probably should refactor to use one of two methods:

- Dependency Injection
- Interface and Wrappers

## Dependency Injection (DI)

DI means instead of having the method determine the date, you pass it in.

This method . . .

```
public void DoSomething()
{
   var now = DateTimeOffSet.Now;
   // Do other stuff with the date
}
```

. . . would change to this method

```
public void DoSomething(DateTimeOffSet dtos)
{
   // Do other stuff with the date
}
```

## Interface and Wrapper

Your other option (although in the end you would use DI with this too) is to create an Interface and a Wrapper. Then use you the interface in your object instead of a concrete DateTimeOffSet, so you can then use MOQ or other testing library to moq the interface. Check out SystemWrapper (https://github.com/jozefizso/SystemWrapper) project for an example.